# HR tag is it possible to create one in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is just a question

is it possible to create a hr tag in `javascript` or `Jquery` without coding any `HTML`?

Comment: Exactly what you are looking for? Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create an hr tag and append it wherever you want to in the HTML document.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gNSWF/3/)**

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hr').click(function(){
       var foo = "<hr/>";
       $('#sample').after(foo);        
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the createElement() and appendChild() methods:

```
var element = document.createElement('hr');
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In JavaScript:

```
var hr = document.createElement('hr');
```

in jQuery:

```
var hr = $('<hr />')[0]; // leave off the [0] if you want it wrapped in a jQuery object
```